# Symfony Doctrine Dynamic Configuration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I currently have a problem with doctrine connexion on my Symfony 3 project.

here is the connection diagram to the database that I should implement:

1 - request on a external database containing the server, login and application database password

2 - decrypt password

3 - configuration / doctrine connection

I don't know if I should rather work on `config.yml` or with another method?

What is the recommended method in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar in a project of mine, here's my working solution:

First, define a empty connection into your config.yml

```
dynamic_con:
    dbname:   ~
    user:     ~
    password: ~
    host:     ~
    charset:  UTF8
```

Now, I've written an `PostLoginController`, which will always be called after an successful login.

There, I get my connection data and call my `DynamicDatabaseService` with it.

My `DynamicDatabaseService` has the following function, that will construct my connection with the data provided.

```
public function getDynamicDatabase() 
{
    // $this->doctrine was given to the service in the constructor beforehand
    $dynamicCon = $this->doctrine->getConnection('dynamic_con');
    $refCon = new \ReflectionObject($dynamicCon);
    $refParams = $refCon->getProperty('_params');
    $refParams->setAccessible('public');
    if($params == false){
        $defaultCon = $this->doctrine->getConnection('default');
        $params = $refParams->getValue($dynamicCon);

        // You need to inject your Params to the function or implement some further logic to receive your connection parameters to use them here.
        $params['dbname'] = $dbName;
        $params['user'] = $dbUser;
        $params['password'] = $dbPass;
        $params['host'] = $dbHost;
        }

    $refParams->setValue($dynamicCon,$params);
    $refParams->setAccessible('private');

    return $dynamicCon;
}
```

Now, you can work with the `$dynamicCon` as a normal PDO Connection, so

```
$dynamicCon->prepare("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE id = :id"); 
$dynamicCon->bindValue(":id", $id);
$dynmicCon->execute();
```

And so on

Comment: Thanks for your reply !